# clipAndEnableScrolling when parent doesn't have fixed height?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am having some problems with clipAndEnableScrolling, it works fine for VGroup when the parent has fixed height, but if the parent doesn't have a fixed height then it doesn't work and the content spills over. e.g:

```
      <s:TitleWindow width="500" height="500">

          <s:VGroup width="100%">

            <s:Group width="100%">

              <!-- The content in here changes height based on the state, I won't complicate this example with the details -->

            </s:Group>   

            <s:Group width="100%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

                    <s:Scroller height="100%" width="100%">
                        <s:DataGroup dataProvider="{someData}" width="100%">

                            <s:layout>
                                <s:VerticalLayout gap="1"/>
                            </s:layout>

                        </s:DataGroup>

                    </s:Scroller>
            </s:Group>

         </s:VGroup>

       </s:TitleWindow>
```

This is a contrived example, but the point is that I don't know the hight of the first group ahead of time so can't set the height of the second group, also the component in reality is quite a lot more complex that the contrived example above so I don't want to have to perform any kind of gymnastics to calculate the heights of everything above the second Group.

Can anyone tell me how to get a scrollbar on the second group?

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting height to 100% upon all the groups, something like this

```
 <s:TitleWindow width="500" height="500">

      <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">

        <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">

          <!-- The content in here changes height based on the state, I won't complicate this example with the details -->

        </s:Group>   

        <s:Group width="100%" height="100%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

                <s:Scroller height="100%" width="100%">
                    <s:DataGroup dataProvider="{someData}" width="100%" height="100%">

                        <s:layout>
                            <s:VerticalLayout gap="1"/>
                        </s:layout>

                    </s:DataGroup>

                </s:Scroller>
        </s:Group>

     </s:VGroup>

   </s:TitleWindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your group inside the scroller.

```
            <s:Scroller height="100%" width="100%">
                <s:DataGroup dataProvider="{someData}" width="100%" height="100%">

                    <s:layout>
                        <s:VerticalLayout gap="1"/>
                    </s:layout>

                </s:DataGroup>

            </s:Scroller>
    </s:Group>
```